# detect upload window close jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

How to fire an event as the windows for file uploading is closed in any of this case - some file selected, different file selected(from the previously selected one ), the window just was closed.

this works only in case if I select some file and it is different from the previously selected one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#file').change(function(){
              alert("test");
        });

    });
```

`<input type="file" id="file" />`

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You need to handle the window's `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` events

Comment: Thanks for the response, but could you please be more specific about how to use them, I surfed the internet of their usage, but could not figure it out. Thanks !